# Esri Print Task doesnt render certain graphics on the map

Tags: graphics, arcgis, angular7, asp.net-core-2.1, esri

My team is building a web application with angular 7 as front end and .net core as back-end.
We are using the print task widget function to generate the image of the map. The problem we are facing is that we have some graphics layers that indicate the position of roadblocks on the map and these roadblocks dont show up on the map when you print it. We have a polygon that the user draws on the map and it shows up , but not the roadblocks.

The code for printing the map can be found in this post of mine. 
[Esri proxy for Angular 7 project to screenshot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54087233/esri-proxy-for-angular-7-project-to-screenshot)

following is a code snippet of how i am setting the roadblock symbol

```
 // symbols
        this.roadblockPointSymbol = { // symbol used for points
          type: 'picture-marker',  // autocasts as new PictureMarkerSymbol()
          url: 'assets/img/button-roadblock.png',
          width: '20px',
          height: '20px'
        };
```

this is the screenshot of the map. The red symbols depicts the roadblocks.
[image]

however when i print the map,this is the result i get
[image]

Has anyone encountered this issue?